# how to map url in grails 1.3.3 UrlMappings

Tags: grails

hi i want to map a url in grails  UrlMappings.groovy file .

if i got "/test/testAction/" then i want to replace "/test/testAction" means i want to remove '/' from last url please suggest me.
I am using this code

```
static mappings = {
      "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
                constraints {
                    // apply constraints here
                }
            }

      "/test/testAction/"(controller: "test", action:"testAction")


}
```

Comment: May I ask why ? I don't see what you are trying to do. Plus, since Grails use CoC, /test/testAction/ is mapped to controller test and testAction by default

Comment: i want to map if i hit /test/testAction/ url then its map to /test/testAction only means i want to remove the forward slash.

Comment: can any body identify my problem . please let me know